# Including variables in a custom select statement in WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

My custom select statement:

```
$querystr = "
    SELECT $wpdb->posts.* 
    FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->comments
    WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->comments.comment_post_ID
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post'
    GROUP BY $wpdb->posts.ID
    ORDER BY comment_count DESC
";
```

My aim is to limit the results returned to a particular set of post authors.

I have an array of WordPress post author user IDs in a variable `$user_ids`.

I thought about adding the following to my select statement, but I'm sure the following syntax isn't the right way to do it:

```
AND $wpdb->posts.post_author = $user_ids
```

Hoping someone can help show me the right way to do this?

Comment: Is `$user_ids` array or a string? If it is array, you will need to implode it and make it "IN"

Comment: $user_ids is an array of values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `$user_ids` are coma separated values then you can do this

```
  AND $wpdb->posts.post_author in ( $user_ids)
```

if `$user_ids` is an array then use this :

```
   AND $wpdb->posts.post_author in ( implode( ',', $user_ids ))
```

Comment: `$user_ids` is currently an array of values. should I do this `implode( ',', $user_ids )` first to get the comma separated values?

Answer (score 1):

First you should make a string:

`$user_ids_string = implode(',',$user_ids)`

then your syntax will be:

`AND $wpdb->posts.post_author in ($user_ids_string)`

Note: If your ids are not integers you should also wrap them with quotes `''`